# Making a 40,000 mAh external battery

Tags: batteries

I have 2 power banks:

- Anker 20,000 mAh powercore.
- Mophie 20,000 mAh

The Anker has 6 of the 18650 cells and 
the mophie has 8 of the 18650s. What I'm am trying to do is combine these cells to make a 40,000 mAh battery and be able to use effectively.

Is it possible to combine all the cells to the motherboard and charge all as one battery?

Comment: It's possible but not without a fairly clever [BMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_management_system).

Comment: All the cells should be in parallel, so should be possible, likely even with the original controller circuit board from 1 of your power banks, generally they do not include an expected capacity, rather build them to make sure it does not under or over charge

Comment: @Reroute - you said *All the cells should be in parallel* -  I think you should read the question more carefully especially the bits marked "cells x 6" and "cells x 8".

Comment: No, I understand that perfectly, it is a USB power bank, they tend to be 1SXP so the power banks are likely 1S6P and 1S8P, adding additional cells in parallel does not change how the BMS works provided it doesn't have charge timer or capacity lockouts, so if he added both sets in parallel, the built in BMS from 1 of the power banks should already suit,

Comment: I had to edit my question to make sure its understood correctly what's wanted

Comment: @Kakarot: It's 'mAh', not 'mah'. Capitals matter in units and brand names. I fixed them all and you've unfixed some of them. There's also a space between the numbers and the units as in '5 cars', not '5cars'.

Comment: @Reroute OK dude.

Comment: If I'm getting this correct, I can open the anker power bank, add the 8 extra 18650s and everything should charge as on battery?

Comment: @Kakarot, now you've got 'MAh' (mega-amp-hour) and 'Mah' (wrong) instead of 'mAh' (milli-amp-hour). A mega-amp-hour battery would be suitable for powering a fleet of submarines. These are all SI standard prefixes and units so you need to learn them if you are to communicate clearly..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but highly inadvisable. Here are a couple of reasons for that:

1. When manufactured, the cells in the power bank are sorted and matched closely by their internal resistance and voltage, to ensure you get full capacity out of the bank. When cells are closely matched like that there is very little interaction happening between the cells (that would be wasted power), and you get the most efficient use of the cells because they charge and discharge "as one". Mismatched cells from two different banks would waste power internally.
2. Safety of the bank benefits from the cell matching done by the manufacturer. The most dangerous thing that can happen is overcharging, followed by excessively discharging the individual cell. In a matched bank, the battery management system monitors the voltage level of the cells and usually their temperature to get a grasp on when to stop the charge from flowing in and out of the bank. Most banks do not monitor individual cells in parallel packs, they operate on the assumption of matched cells, which you won't have if you mix two banks.